# Type of verb in context

Tags: verbs

In general, verbs are used to show one of three things:

1. An action (e.g. the action of kicking in *He kicked the ball*)
2. A state of being (e.g. the state of looking sad in *He looked sad*)
3. An occurrence (e.g. *become* in *She became a politician*)

Now consider the below sentence.

> The cliffs stand high and tall.

Is the verb 'stand' a verb of being (stative) or a verb of doing?

Comment: Which do you think it might be, and why?

Comment: "Stand" in the cited context is a ***stative*** verb - equivalent to *The cliffs **are** high and tall,* but with a little bit of "emphasis / immediacy" added by the choice of verb. The same would apply with, for example, *The cliffs **loom** high and tall* (or ***tower,*** or whatever).